# The fastest way to find an element in an array with a given property name and replace it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, redux, ngrx

I have a performance issue with NgRx, I have an array with thousands of objects that looks like this (I can't change that structure even I don't like it):

`state.alarms` structure:

```
[
 { global: {...} },
 { 282: {...} }, 
 { 290: {...} },
 { 401: {...} }
 etc...
]
```

[image]

`addNewAlarm(state, alarm)` here alarm object is for example:

```
{ 282: {...} }
```

As you can see the object looks something like this `{ someNumber: nestedObjectForThatNumber }`

I'm listening for changes and if some appear I have to replace object where "the key" is given number.

In the case from the screenshot for example I get `{ 282: {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3} }` so I have to replace the item of array with index 1.

In my reducer I've created something like this but it doesn't work as I expected:

```
export function addNewAlarm(state: State, alarm: AlarmsObject): State | undefined {
  const alarms: AlarmsObject[] = [...state.alarms];
  if (state) {
    const existingRecord = state.alarms.find(alarm1 => alarm1.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(alarm)[0]));
    if (existingRecord) {
      const index = state.alarms.indexOf(existingRecord);
      alarms[index] = alarm;
    }
  }

  return { ...state, alarms };
}
```

Maybe someone can give me a hint how to do it in a right way?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially where it says, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: It would be best to gather the output of `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`. The console does funny things to objects when printing things out. For instance, I expect those keys are actually strings, but are displayed as numbers by whatever is displaying it.

Comment: Yes excatly, those keys are strings. The actuall data in my case is too nested to paste it here so I've used `{...}` for that

Comment: So, there's a few things odd here. If I were you, I'd check if state is provided before trying to get `alarms` off of it and quit early if so, like `if (!state) { return state; }` Then, I'm not sure what you're doing with the `find`. Can you explain `alarm[index] = alarm;`? That's going to create an odd nesting structure...

Comment: There was a typo,  - it's `alarmS[index] = alarm`. I wrote this code here without IDE as an example, I know I need to handle one more case and add a non-existent element. With find i'm just checking if there is the element where property name (key) is the same as in the object I get from API.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question showing an example of how `addNewAlarm` is called? I'm having trouble picturing the structure of `alarm`, `alarms` (which doesn't appear to be defined), and `state.alarms`. Just want to make sure we get you the best answer we can.

Comment: Instead of using `find()` and after `indexOf()`, you could use `findIndex()` instead, this will give you the index directly and might improve performance.  
NOTE: when the element is not found `findIndex()` will return `-1`

Comment: I've just edited it. So in the `state.alarms` you have something like the example that I posted, and alarm argument of `addNewAlarm` method looks like one of those object of array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (If not found return -1) but, why not create an object?

```
    stateObj: any = {};

    this.state.forEach((x) => {
      this.stateObj = { ...this.stateObj, ...x };
    });
```

So you only need use

```
//Note you needn't return anything
addNewAlarm(stateObj: any, alarm: AlarmsObject){
    const key=Object.keys(alarm)[0]
    this.stateObj[key]=this.alarm[key]
}
```

A [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-namhre?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)